# Flask 500'ding and I'm not sure why

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Im trying to piece together a flask app to play around with python and flask. It's got an Avengers theme (anyone seen how cool that movie is?!). Anyways, I keep getting 500's when I hit the /dashboard path and I'm not sure why. Care to help me out?

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, abort, jsonify
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


## ##  ####  ####   #####  #
# # #  #  #  #   #  ###    #
#   #  ####  ####   #####  ####
class Ticket(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index = True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), index = True)
    whatWentWrong = db.Column(db.String(5000))

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Ticket"

    def __init__(self, email, name, whatWentWrong):
        self.email = email
        self.name = name
        self.whatWentWrong = whatWentWrong



  #    ####  ####
 ###   ####  ####
#   #  #     #
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def activate_shield_defense_mechanism():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/dashboard')
def admin():
    try:
        data = Ticket.query.all()
    except:
        data = None
    print vars(data)
    return render_template('dashboard.html', data=data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

C:\Users\%%%%%%%\ShieldVirtualEnv\Scripts\python.exe            C:/Users/%%%%%%%/PycharmProjects/SHIELD/SHIELD.py
[21/Apr/2014 19:52:52] "GET /dashboard HTTP/1.1" 500 -

Comment: Did you just forget to properly format the admin function? As the rest of it is correct I just wanted to make sure. Are you using the builtin flask server? If so, what does print vars(data) spit out? And what does the template that data is being put into look like?

Comment: So, I cut everything out of the template to see if that was causing the issue, and its still 500'ing before that.  vars(data) is never hit, I believe because of Ticket.Query.all() causing the issue. Im using SQLAlchemy and have never had an issue with this until now though.Yup, built in server.

Comment: Also fixed the formatting issue from pasting into stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out, actually. Should have just keep playing with it for another 20 minutes before I posted. Anyways, The issue was that Ticket.query.all() returns an array, not a dict, and vars() was not having that. Simply changing it to be `print data` worked out fine.